# use type_traits to limit type of template member function

Tags: c++, type-traits

I'm writing a template class with a method that performs some bitwise operations, so I want to limit the type in the case this method is used within `is_integral`. I took the simple example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) and modified a bit as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class A
{
  public:
    A();

    T foo(T i) {
        static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Integer required.");
        return (i & 2);
    }

  private:
    T x;
};

int main() {
  A<double> a;
  std::cout << a.foo(3) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

However, compiler gives me 2 compile errors at `static_assert()`:

```
static_assert failed "Integer required."
```

and at `return (i & 2);`:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')
```

My question is, if it will show the error at line `return (i & 2);` anyway, using `type_traits` to check for type here seems useless? And, is there anyway to throw the error to console output when it runs, instead of making it unable to be compiled?

Comment: Qt is not C++ compiler, so you have to name your compiler.

Comment: `And, is there anyway to throw the error to console output when it runs` defeats the purpose of any static_assert

Comment: @AnatolyS, while Qt is indeed not a compiler, the actual compiler is not relevant to the question. I will edit it and remove Qt.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, if it will show the error at line `return (i & 2);` anyway, using `type_traits` to check for type here seems useless?

It's true that it's unfortunate that you get subsequent compile errors anyway, but which compile error do you find more readable?

- "Integer required."
- invalid operands to binary expression (`double` and `double`)

I know what I did wrong about the first one - I have `A<double>` but `foo()` requires an integer. No idea about the second. Am I misusing your class template or does it have a bug?

> And, is there anyway to throw the error to console output when it runs, instead of making it unable to be compiled?

You *want* it to be a compile error. Catching errors at compile time is a lot better than catching errors at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is trying to report as many errors as it can. `static_assert` reports an error, but there is another error as well (using `double` argument for `&`) so it also is reported.

If you want to limit output to one error, you should have two sfinae-enabled overloads and have a second one (for anything but integrals) consist of a single `static_assert`.

As for your last question, the whole purpose of doing `static_assert` is to trigger errors at **compile** time, not runtime.

Comment: for the last question, yes i knew it, i meant to ask if there is a way (of course other than `static_assert`) to trigger and throw that error only at runtime, since compiler always realizes the error with bitwise operations ... like `Error: at function XXX at line YYY`

Comment: @scmg, why do you want to do this? This is an error which is 100% detectable during compile time. Why do you want to report it during runtime? People are spending considerable efforts to report as much as they can at compile time, why do you want to go in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to achieve the same thing. You may or may not prefer the error messages:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
class A
{
  public:
    A();

    T foo(T i) {
        return (i & 2);
    }

  private:
    T x;
};

int main() {
  A<double> a;
  std::cout << a.foo(3) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

sample errors:

```
In file included from /opt/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/move.h:57:0,
from /opt/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
from /opt/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
from /opt/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/char_traits.h:39,
from /opt/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/ios:40,
from /opt/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/ostream:38,
from /opt/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/iostream:39,
from /tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler11636-75-1ve7gbt/example.cpp:1:
/opt/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value; _Tp = void]':
19 : required from here
/opt/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/type_traits:2388:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
^
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler11636-75-1ve7gbt/example.cpp: In function 'int main()':
19 : error: template argument 2 is invalid
A<double> a;
^
20 : error: request for member 'foo' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'int'
std::cout << a.foo(3) << std::endl;
^
Compilation failed
```